# sbt error after adding sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-activator, sbt-native-packager

I created a simple project using typesafe activator:

```
activator new helloapp hello-play-scala
```

If I run **sbt** command inside the **helloapp** directory it works

Now I edit **project/plugins.sbt** and add the following line:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.3")
```

If I run **sbt** command inside the **hellopapp** directory I get the following error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/blr/kubeplayground/gultenetwork/project
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/AutoPlugin
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening.

Comment: What is the SBT version in `project/build.properties`?

Comment: The version is 0.13.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of `sbt-native-packager` is an AutoPlugin and they were only added in SBT 0.13.5. The current SBT version is 0.13.11, update to it.